# Sci-fi movie about a video game with enemies on motorcycles

Tags: story-identification, movie, video-games

I'm trying to find a movie based on a single scene I've seen, as a child, so the movie must have been from the 80's or beginning of the 90's. From what I can remember, I would say about the same period as Aliens, as the visual effects seemed quite similar. The ambiance was really sci-fi/film noir. The scene goes like this:

The main character is a soldier (possibly asian?), heavily armed and in black armor (starship tropers-like armor, with helmet). The scene starts with him in an elevator, hitting his guns against each others, waiting for the doors to open. The elevator doors open and a bunch of bad guys are racing towards him on motorcycles; he shoots at them with his guns and kills them all. He proceeds out of the elevator and ends up facing a woman yielding a sword or a saber, that cuts both of his hands. He looks at his severed limbs while screaming, then she chops his head off.

At this point I'm not really sure what happened, but it seemed to me like the scene was actually a video game and that the soldier was actually the main character's avatar; he and his friend are trying to decipher what to do to beat the enemies of the level.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is actually a scene from the X-Files episode [First Person Shooter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Person_Shooter_%28The_X-Files%29) (season 7, 13th episode; aired in 2000).

I don't believe the full episode is available publicly, but this may be the second half of the scene described.

The episode deals with an immersive video game, where an unexpected character (the woman) kills people in the game, causing identical wounds in the real world. The asian man described would be Darryl Musashi, who was brought in to remove the swordswoman. He defeats the standard enemies with ease, but has his hands chopped off upon meeting his target.

[This promo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZRj-6bMeBs) briefly shows the described bad guys on motorcycles.

Comment: [Hulu link to the episode](https://www.hulu.com/watch/a2df0fb4-5bae-461e-9f23-e7784ad99623)